# Succinct and light-weight API: REST+JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json, rest

**Summary:** I need to know if there is an existing light-weight implementation of REST+JSON in .NET world which does not use WCF. If not, I am looking for some folks who would be interested to start a joint venture for an Open Source project.

I do not know about you but I was a big fan of WCF when it came out and I praised its design for its modularity and extensibility. However, as I used it more and more often, fundamental issues started to come into light to the point that I now feel it has to be scrapped and redesigned. That seems to be a big statement but I believe these are major issues:

1. First of all, WCF internally uses SOAP for message which means if the transport message is not SOAP, we incur the cost of transforming to and back from SOAP for every call. This is expensive and time consuming.
2. Transforming the outgoing message requires "plugging in" a message inspector and "stealing" the message. As the name implies, this is an inspector (must be used for inspection and logging) so using that for changing the message is frankly a hack.
3. It was design according to WSDL and the world has changed so much since 2001. Implementing REST also requires stealing the message. WCF was designed according to WSDL and not REST.
4. Channel stack is unnecessarily heavy.
5. The main stack is protocol agnostic. This is not a advantage, it is a fundamental flaw. As you know, access to a lot of protocol level information was added later because was impossible to implement some important user scenarios. For example, client’s IP address in TCP was not accessible and added later (now accessible using perationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name])
6. Interoperability with other platforms can be an issue.

Now it seems that a lot of designs are moving towards simplicity of JSON and REST. I just love their simplicity and I can see my washing machine consuming JSON in 5-10 years and hosting a REST service! I believe their implementation in .NET was a hack and we seriously need a very light weight and simple framework (because these are simple and light weight) to host REST+JSON services inside and outside IIS. I hope such a framework exist but if not, I am really eager to get something going with a number of like-minded folks.

So what do you think? Does such a framework exist? If not, is anyone interested?

Comment: Have you thought about using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Isn't transforming to SOAP only done for the HTTP bindings? Not for TCP and NamedPipes bindings I believe.

Comment: I believe there are people at Microsoft who agree with you.  See the description of the keynote here http://www.restfest.org/speakers

Comment: @Peladao: I am actually not talking about encoding of the message (which can be XML, MTOM and binary). Encoding happens much later. In fact in HTTP (ws and basic), message is SOAP so it does not need to be transformed to SOAP because it already is SOAP.

Comment: @Darrel: Thanks mate. I actually was expecting a new release of WCF (an almost total re-write) sometime soon and it seems I wasn't  too far off.

Comment: @Aliostad This is not a rewrite of WCF, just a new stack for HTTP using the WCF channel model.  If all goes well, I should be broadcasting Glenn's keynote on Friday via UStream.  We'll post a link on the RESTfest website.

Comment: @Darrel If it is a parallel/separate stack, it would call it a re-write...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC that spits out JSON instead of HTML seems like a possibility. You have the freedom to either use the JsonDataContractSerializer or JSON.Net to serialize your datacontracts.

Comment: Good answer! I think this combination covers most of my requirement. But it depends on having an IIS and hosting a light REST+JSON service should not necessarily require IIS. I am currently using WCF to host services for inter-process communication and no reason thsis could not be JSON+REST.

Comment: Why is the outside IIS requirement? IIS itself is quite lean and mean.

Comment: A lot of companies do not allow IIS on client machines. In the connected world of today (and more in the future) each device should/eventually will be able to host JSON+REST services.

Comment: You will need a proxy application like IIS, if a company doesn't allow IIS it's most likely there isn't a single way to reach a machine from the internet.

Comment: I will explore more on this route and I can use IIS for now. But I can see that time coming soon where devices talk REST+JSON and they need to be able to host it. OpenRasta still depends on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta/wiki/Doc). It looks like it addresses many of your concerns.

Comment: This still depends on IIS. Is there anything without IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use IIS, you can implement your own HTTP listener process. This let's you write your own standalone application to respond to HTTP requests (which may be run as a service if you so desire) without any of the overhead of IIS, WCF or any other container process framework. Your process would live on top of the HTTP.sys functionality exposed by Windows, and exposed by the .Net framework through the HttpListener class.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Note that you will need to write your own infrastructure for matching incoming requests and dispatching them to corresponding handlers (the equivalent of ASP.Net MVC's UrlRoutingModule/RouteTable.Routes/MvcRouteHandler), and you will need to flow the HttpListenerContext everywhere in order to examine the incoming request and complete it. But this gives you the ultimate in flexibility in what you can do.

And it certainly performs - I have benchmarked a basic HttpListener implementation on a standard desktop-class machine at over 3000 requests served/second, so the framework itself will not hold you back.

Answer (score -1):

There is [MicroRest](https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/microrest/wiki/Home), an open source project I started a while. Here's the blurb I wrote:

> MicroRest is a tiny REST framework - 5 classes, around 500 lines of code. All output is JSON. It allows you to add REST capabilities to your ASP.NET applications without needing to go through the huge ugly mess of WCF rest (which doesn't provide 'clean' URLs in 3.5). It also allows you to use POCOs (and complex objects in some cases) inside your REST methods, where WCF restricts you to using ints and strings

Contributions are very welcome - it does rely on System.Web.Routing right now, so needs Cassini/IISExpress as an embedded web server. I'm looking at writing a custom route parser so it can move to Kayak as some point.

Comment: With ASP.NET Web API implementing most of the HTTP spec, do you think we still yet need another framework? I surely value any OSS effort but I think WebAPI will become de-facto.

Comment: @Aliostad the framework is aimed specifically at 3.5 rather than ASP.NET MVC 4 (I'm not sure ASP.NET webforms has rest capabilities anyway?). The world doesn't need another framework but there is actually only WCF right now, the others such as nancy and stackservice are fairly isoteric in their usage. MicroRest also lets you put your API inside your core/domain layer

Comment: Good luck mate. I have been picking up on ASP.NET Web API and I really like it.

Comment: @Aliostad I wish I could use the webapi, MicroRest was built mostly for 3 legacy ASP.NET 2projects