# Capture global WCF ServiceHost request events

Tags: wcf, servicehost, rehosting

I'm using a really simple WCF project which is being hosted by a WPF application. It basically operates as a REST server for dishing up data on my PC. No IIS, and it runs as SingleInstance. **I want to see what IP's are accessing MyService, and what WebMethod they're attempting to invoke.**

Ok so I can have an event as part of my Service, declared in the service class itself. Here's some code that gets it going, it all works exactly as expected (no flames about `m_` please ;)):

```
MyService ds = new MyService(); // It's not really called this :)
ds.Request += new EventHandler(ds_Request); // I want to avoid this
ds.SomePropertySetFromMyRehostingClient = "something"; // SingleInstance now required

m_Service = new ServiceHost(ds, new Uri(GetServerHostUri()));
m_Service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>().InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
m_Service.BeginOpen(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new AsyncCallback(EndStartService), null);
```

Then in each service method, I can raise this event so my app knows that *someone* has tried to use it. Brilliant, but let's face it, this is awful.

I have to write something along the lines of:

```
var who =  OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Via;
var what = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["UriTemplateMatchResults"];
```

for *each service call*.

**Is there a more generic catch-all-event that can detect a call to my service?** There's probably one fired by one of the many Behaviour/ChannelDispatcher types which I admittedly don't fully understand.

Thanks for your help, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IParameterInspector` you can hook to any method calls and inspect the method and/or parameters.

There is no other way to get the extra information (IP address, etc) of the incoming message other than the one you have used. This is just a bad design by Microsoft IMHO (see my rant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710635/succinct-and-light-weight-api-restjson-in-net)).

You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx).

Comment: Yes! That's it! Good stuff, you obviously know all this inside out. I didn't end up actually using the IParameterInspector, rather the IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest() implementation seemed to do the trick. I simply add that in as a Behavior after binding an event which returns the appropriately processed data. Thanks!

Comment: Pleased it worked out for you. I use `IParameterInspector` for auditing calls.